# Setting up a local terrain tile server

Tags: openstreetmap, terrain, dted, stamen

I am setting up an offline tile server. Does anyone know of something similar to OpenStreetMaps and/or Stamenmaps for terrain data that I can use with unfolding or other api?

Comment: If I was looking for open terrain data I would ask on the [opendata.se] Stack Exchange.